# Remove a menu item created by a plugin

Tags: functions, admin-menu, sub-menu

I'm trying to remove a menu item and tried several approaches, but have not had any luck. It was created from a FAQ plugin.

If I use this line:

```
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=question' );
```

It will remove the main menu, however I only want to remove two sub-menu items contained inside that `edit.php?post_type=question` URL address.

For the item I want to remove, the path in the URL bar gives me the following:
`edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-topic&post_type=question`
and
`edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-tags&post_type=question`

I have tried several solutions including `remove_menu_page` and `remove_submenu_page` to no avail.

What has failed so far:

```
remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=question', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-topic&post_type=question');
remove_menu_page( 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-tags') ;
remove_menu_page( 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-tags&post_type=question') ;
remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=question', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-topic&post_type=question');
remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-topic&post_type=question');
remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-topic');
remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'edit-tags.php');
```

Comment: Can you show some of the code that you *have* tried?

Comment: I added it to the top to make it cleaner.

Comment: Were you using your `remove_submenu_page()` and `remove_menu_page()` calls inside an action hook? See [the example on the Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page#Examples).

Comment: Yes I was using it inside an action hook.

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );

function my_remove_menu_pages() {
/*those functions here*/
}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function remove_submenu() {

    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-topic&post_type=question' );
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-tags&post_type=question' );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_submenu', 999 );
```

Please read the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/remove_submenu_page). `remove_submenu_page()` need two parameters and the right hook.

And **very** important: Use a very, very, very high priority in your hook! If you use a low priority, your function will be executed before the menus will be added. So there is no menu to remove. If you use a high priority, there is a good chance that your function will be executed **after** the menus was added.

This could be the tricky part.

**UPDATE**

After installing and inspecting the plugin, I found the solution. There are several issues and a few tricky parts.

The submenus are **not** added with `add_submenu_page()`, they are added with a custom post type. A simple search by `add_submenu_page()`, copy the menu slugs and removing the menus have to fail. I have to search for the cpt slug and use it.

After `global $submenu; var_dump( $submenu );` I get this output

```
[more elements]
    'edit.php?post_type=question' => 
        array (size=7)
          5 => 
            array (size=3)
              0 => string 'FAQs' (length=4)
              1 => string 'edit_posts' (length=10)
              2 => string 'edit.php?post_type=question' (length=27)
          10 => 
            array (size=3)
              0 => string 'Neue FAQ' (length=8)
              1 => string 'edit_posts' (length=10)
              2 => string 'post-new.php?post_type=question' (length=31)
          15 => 
            array (size=3)
              0 => string 'FAQ Titel' (length=9)
              1 => string 'manage_categories' (length=17)
              2 => string 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-topic&amp;post_type=question' (length=55)
          16 => 
            array (size=3)
              0 => string 'FAQ Tags' (length=8)
              1 => string 'manage_categories' (length=17)
              2 => string 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-tags&amp;post_type=question' (length=54)
[ more elements ]
```

Now it was easy to remove the submenus with `edit.php?post_type=question` as menu slug and `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-topic&amp;post_type=question` / `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-tags&amp;post_type=question` as submenu slug.

If you watch carefully, the ampersand (&) is a html entity. It's not possible just to copy the url part and insert it. So you cannot remove a submenu page with a un-encoded url, it have to be url-encoded.

And here is the final code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_faq_subpages', 999 );

function remove_faq_subpages() {

    $ptype = 'question';
    remove_submenu_page( "edit.php?post_type={$ptype}", "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-tags&amp;post_type={$ptype}" );
    remove_submenu_page( "edit.php?post_type={$ptype}", "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=faq-topics&amp;post_type={$ptype}" );

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. The following screenshot will be extremely helpful. I tried to do it a different way... using the variables in the screenshot, but couldnt get it to work. http://s7.postimg.org/7m36rciob/this_might_help.jpg

Comment: Here is a better screenshot, sorry it got clipped short http://s17.postimg.org/uj18k5vvz/FAQ_help.jpg

Comment: Open the plugin, find the line where the menus will be added with `add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );`. Use the `$parent_slug` and `$menu_slug` to remove the submenus.

Comment: I also updatetd my answer. The priority of your hook is very important because the `add_submenu_page()` and the `remove_submenu_page()` use the same hook. Be sure your `remove_submenu_page()` is called very lately.

Comment: Your comments have been useful but Yeah I am not sure how to remove it... even after looking at the faq-manager.php inside this plugin 

I am using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-faq-manager/

I saw the $parent_slug you mention and $menu_slug but that didn't really help me... the $parent_slug we have correct but the $menu_slug is questionable... Maybe you can crack it by looking at the plugin itself.

Comment: And the solution is... ?

Comment: I went the easy route and found a plugin that was able to do it. I used Adminimize and was easily able to do it.

Comment: Oh damn yes, I forgot the possibility to use this plugin. [Frank](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/170/bueltge) recently updated the plugin, it is very good.

Comment: After all, I found the reasons why all solutions failed. At first it was a custom post type and not an submenu page. And the url have to be url-encoded. The plain ampersand (&) in the url won't work.

Comment: @Ralf912 thx. &amp; did the trick after much head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

Make menu item visible only for admin:

```
function hide_admin_menu()
{
    if ( !current_user_can('administrator')) {
        remove_menu_page('wpca');
    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'hide_admin_menu', 999);
```